# Probability: Need a Reference and Context for the concept used

Tags: probability, measure-theory, reference-request

I was reading [this](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/131600/equilibr-editorial) explanation.

The question in concise terms is

> We choose a $n$ tuple of real numbers $(x_1,...,x_n)$ uniformly randomly satisfying $x_i\geq0, ∑x_i=1.$ What is the probability that $\forall x_i: x_i<\frac{1}{2}$

The linked explanation uses the following fact as an assumption.

> $P(a_1+⋯+a_{n-1} < k/2)=(\int_{0<x_1,0<x_n,x_1+...+x_n<k/2} dx...dx_{n-1}) / (\int_{0<x_1,0<x_n,x_1+...+x_n<k} dx...dx_{n-1}) = 1/2^{n-1}$

This is the elaboration given.

> As you see, we consider geometrically similar sets here. Their linear sizes relate to each other as $1:2$ thus volumes of $k$-th degree will relate as $1:2^k$. We are interested in volumes of degree $n−1$ so needed number is equal to $1/2^{n−1}$. From this we get that probability of impossibility to form a polygon is equal to $n/2^{n−1}$

What does it mean by geometrically similar sets?
How can we say that their linear sizes relate as $1:2$? How can we just use that knowledge without any further calculation to say that volumes of $k$-th degreee will realte to as $1:2^k$.

What is the underlying theory being used to answer all these questions. Is it measure theory? I want to rigorously study these. Could you point me to a suitable resource where I can study concepts related to these?
To be precise, My Questions is What is it that I should have known so that I would have been comfortable and found the linked explanation a cakewalk?

Could the given ratio been have calculated using a perhaps more mathematically straightforward way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no need for measure theory, but the notation like $m(A)$ to denoting the size (probability measure) of event $A$ can be convenient.

One can always observe a couple of concrete examples to have a sense of what's going on.

For example, one can visually see when $n = 2$ and $n=3$ that the special threshold of $\frac12$ in each dimension ($X$ for $x_1$, $Y$ for $x_2$, and so on) cuts the whole space into $2^n$ "equal" subspaces.

One can also see that all the arguments to come based on symmetry (being "equal" or similar) will NOT work for any ratios $\sum x_i = r$ other than $r = 1/2$.

In 2-dim, there are $4$ smaller squares inside the unit square, $2$ of which are "similar" to the original "unit square with the event" (off-diagonal $x+y = 1$).

In 3-dim, there are $8$ smaller cubes inside the unit cube, $4$ of which are "similar" to the original unit square with the simplex plane $x+y+z = 1$. While the small triangle in the corner-to-origin part (the central one) is "upside down", really there are only $3$ parts that are exact scaled version of the original "unit cube with event".

[image]

A half-scaled version of the original configuration in 2-dim is of size $\frac14$, and a half-scaled config in 3-dim is of size $\frac18$ of the original.

By half-scaled we mean the linear dimension (side length) is halved. The area goes one-fourth and volume goes one-eighth.

Likewise, a half-scaled in $n$-dim is $\frac1{2^n}$ the original This is just basic geometry and should be pretty intuitive.

Note that the green part (the event), which is the edge of the solid simplex, is one dimensional lower. For example, on the right the triangle is divided into $2^{n-1}$ similar parts.

---

Denote the desired event as $A \equiv \{ x_i < \frac12 ~~\forall\, i\}$ and its complement event as $A^c \equiv \{\text{not all} ~x_i < \frac12\}$.

We will show that the size (measure) of $A^c$ is what you quoted "probability of impossibility to form a polygon", namely, $m(A^c) = \frac{n}{ 2^{n−1} }$.

Then by definition, $m(A) = 1 - m(A^c)$ is what we are after.

---

Note that $A^c$ always has exactly one of $x_i$ failing the requirement: either it is $x_1 > 1/2$, or it is $x_2 > 1/2$, or ... , or it is $x_n > 1/2$. Due to the definition of $\sum x_i = 1$, there cannot be two simultaneous $x_i > 1/2$ and $x_j > 1/2$ for $i \neq j$.

Formally, $A^c$ consists of $n$ disjoint sub-events: for $i = 1$ to $n$ 
$$B_i \equiv \{ x_i > 1/2,\, x_j < 1/2 ~~\forall\, j \neq i\}\, , \qquad A^c = \bigcup_i B_i$$

**Due to the symmetry** ($x_i$ are interchangeable), we thus know that the $B_i$ are "copies" to each other:

$$m(B_1) = m(B_2) = \ldots = m(B_n) \equiv p_B \, , \qquad m(A^c) = n \cdot p_B$$

To figure out $p_B$, one can go through the geometric argument you quoted: each piece is a half-scaled version of the original configuration thus $1/2^{n-1}$ of the original measure (total probability).

Algebraically, we can do this with a bit more rigor.

Shift the failed component $x_i$ to have a new combo **within each sub-event** $B_i$ (given $i$)

$$\begin{cases} w_i \equiv x_i - \frac12 & \\
w_j \equiv x_j & ~\forall j \neq i
\end{cases} \qquad \text{such that} \sum_k w_k = 1-\frac12 = \frac12 ~~\text{and}~~ w_k \in (0,\frac12)~~\forall\, k = 1 \sim n$$

Now we see that each $B_i$ is the half-scaled version of the original event $$m(B_i) = \frac{ m(A) }{ 2^{n-1} }$$ in that comparing with originally for event $A$ we have
\begin{align} 
\sum_k w_k &= \frac12 &&~\text{and} & w_k &\in (0,\frac12) &&~\forall\, k = 1 \sim n \\
\sum_k x_k &= 1 &&~\text{and} & x_k &\in (0,1) &&~\forall\, k = 1 \sim n
\end{align}
where one should note that each set $w_k$ are mutually independent (even with $i$ given) just like how the original $x_k$ are independent (free to vary within the specified range) up to the degree of $n-1$.

In particular, in $2$-dim the desired event $m(A) = 1 - m(A^c) = 1 - \frac{ n }{ 2^{n-1}} = 1 - \frac{ 2 }{ 2^{2-1}} = 0$ has zero measure, as it is a just a point in the left figure above.

In $3$-dim the desired event is $1 - \frac{ 3 }{ 2^{3-1}} = \frac14$ as the "central" piece in the right figure above.

Please let me know if there's anything that needs to be further clarified.

Comment: In 2 dim, square is divided into four parts. Why are only two similar to the original square? Similarly for cube, why do you say only four are similar to the original one?
`While the small triangle in the corner-to-origin part (the central one) is "upside down", really there are only 3 parts that are exact scaled version of the original "unit cube with event".`
You say triangle. Are you talking about parts of simplex or parts of cube?

Comment: Why won't the scaling argument work when r is not 1/2. Aren't the sets $\sum w_k = 1/3, w_k \in (0,1/3)  \forall  k = 1 \sim n$  **and** $\sum w_k = 1, w_k \in (0,1) \forall k = 1 \sim n$ related as $\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}$

Comment: You are right to raise the question about my wording. I wanted my sentences to be more readable and hope my figures would help explain. When I said the "space" is divided into $2^{n}$, I mean just the Euclidean unit square or unit cube itself, ignoring the "event" of interest. When you includes the "event" (the corresponding simplex), then in 2-dim there are only two "parts" that carries the "event" that is similar to the original unit-square-with-off-diagonal. Namely, only the top left "part" and the bottom right "part" have the green line within.

Comment: Similarly, like you said, in 3-dim, "the exact scaled version" means the smaller cubes that carry the simplex. The unit cube is dived in 8 parts, but 4 of them are "empty space", without pieces of the simplex. The 4 parts that carry the events mean those smaller cubes (space) with green pieces within. When referring to the figure "the central one" means central to our view.

Comment: Lastly, when the cutting is not half-half $r \neq 1/2$, there will be "rectangular" parts that are not similar to the original space whatsoever. For example, in 2-dim and $r = 1/3$ as you suggested, there are still going to be 4 parts, but while 2 of them are squares (one bigger then the other) the other two are rectangles. In 3-dim after the cut you'll have "columns" and "slabs" along with still only two cubes.

Comment: Your comments clarify what you meant completely. You should have put these explanations in the answer itself. 
Thanks for taking the time to write a detailed answer. Which tool did you use to draw the figures?

Comment: I am not sure if you are right about other ratios. when $r = 1/3$, in the 2 dim case, you can divide the square in a $3$ X $3$ grid where each cell is of equal size. So, each cell is $1/9$ of the original square. Intuitively, this can be extended to $n$ dimensions, although i am not sure. Please spend some time to think about this.

Comment: The figures you see in this post was done in Mathematica (Wolfram). Occasionally I use GeoGebra when it comes to plane geometry. As for how I can improve (make clear) the post, indeed I need to work on it more. Actually I myself often give others the advice to not provide info in the comments but in the post. Here I didn't want the post to be longer than it is, and I also feel like I in the comments was basically repeating what is said in the comments.... but apparently you as a reader has a different view.

Comment: As for the dividing ratio, I was referring to cutting one-third-and-two-thirds, with a total of only 4 sub-squares. What you are saying about 3-by-3 is correct for sure in itself (yes you CAN imagine such cutting), but that is not what's happening with the actual problem you were originally considering.

Comment: I guess I've digressed from the orginal problem. But is this correct or not: $\sum w_k = 1/3 ,w_k \in (0,1/3) \forall k = 1 \sim n $and $\sum w_k = 1 ,w_k \in (0,1) \forall k = 1 \sim n $ related as $\frac{1}{3^{n−1}}$

Comment: Yes, geometrically the size of the $(n-1)$-simplex of side lengths $L/3$ has $1/3^{n-1}$ the volume of a $(n-1)$-simplex of side lengths $L$. My previous comment "...not what's happening with the actual problem..." meant that the probability of "not all $\sum x_i < 1/3$" is not $n/3^{n-1}$.

Comment: One can translate the essential part of a probability problem to a purely geometrical problem (and we did with the half-half cut), but a variation on that geometrical fact doesn't necessarily goes back to a variation of that original probability problem.

Comment: The 2-dim case of 3-by-3 grid itself is nice, but it doesn't give you the answer for "probability of $x_1 < 1/3$ AND $x_2 < 1/3$ given $x_1 + x_2 = 1$".

Comment: Hey. It can be used for calculating probability "$x_1,....,x_n < 2/3 $ given $x_1+...+x_n = 1$. That would be $1-\frac{n}{3^{n-1}}$. But it doesn't matter. When you said it wouldn't work for any $r$ other than $1/3$, i had to confirm (don't want incorrect maths knowledge), irrespective of whether a probability problem can be solved using that.

Comment: oh that's a very neat observation! As of now I'm not entirely sure if this "less than $2/3$" version is correct for $n \geq 3$ and how the details work (there seems to be some overlapping that one can successfully deal with). This can actually make an interesting new question post.